# Huggingface language modeling stuck at data reading phase

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a large file (1 GB+) with a mix of short and long texts (format: wikitext-2) for fine tuning the masked language model with *bert-large-uncased*
 as baseline model. I followed the instruction at https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling. The process seems to be stuck at a stage "`Creating features from dataset file at <file loc>`". I am unsure what is wrong, is it really stuck or does it take really long for file of this size?

Command looks pretty much this:

```
export TRAIN_FILE=/path/to/dataset/my.train.raw
export TEST_FILE=/path/to/dataset/my.test.raw

python run_language_modeling.py \
    --output_dir=local_output_dir \
    --model_type=bert \
    --model_name_or_path=local_bert_dir \
    --do_train \
    --train_data_file=$TRAIN_FILE \
    --do_eval \
    --eval_data_file=$TEST_FILE \
    --mlm
```

Added: The job is running on CPU

Comment: Could you add additional information like how much RAM does your system have etc

Comment: 61 GB RAM 8 vCPU on AWS

Comment: It seems RAM/compute should not be a bottleneck. For how long did you let the process run? These things can taker a good amount of time, especially when the data generation is done on a single processor/

Comment: I haven't tried it, but try to add `use_fast=True` in the lines (186 and 188) with `tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(.....`. This will load the [rust tokenizer implementation](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers) which is much faster.

Comment: I resolved the problem by switching over to larger GPU spec and reducing the batch size. Appreciate all the responses

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is huge, I would strongly recommend trying your code on a toy dataset before running it on your actual large data. This will be helpful when you debug too.

If your system has multi-cores, please follow some multi-processing strategies. Take a look at https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning.

Comment: Lightning actually has a feature for this https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fast_training.html